# Ember.js: Computed property from child models

Tags: ember.js

in my Ember.js application I have models: item, module, rank with following structure: item hasMany modules, each module can have a rank and rank has property score.

Item is my model for controller. I want to show sums of all scores from all modules. So I want to create computed property, however I have no idea how to write the dependency in `.property("name_of_property")`. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  sum: Ember.computed('model.modules.[]', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    this.get('model.modules').mapBy('rank.score').forEach(function(score) {
      sum = sum + score;
    });
    return sum;
  })
});
```

When defining the `sum` property you are setting the dependency like this `model.modules.[]`, that means that when the `modules` RecordArray changes, either a new `module` has been added or removed, this computed property would be called again.

Hope it helps.